# JavaScript text editor with cursor jumping functionality

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm triing to implement a custom JavaScript text editor with CodeMirror. I've implemented a feature, which inserts the following code to the textarea of the editor when I click on a button:

```
if () then () else ()
```

After the insertion I would like to position the cursor between the first brackets. When the user pushes tab button the cursor should jump between the second brackets, and if he/she pushes it again the cursor should jump betweeb the third one. How can I implement it?

Thank You in advance.